# How to generate authentication token after FormsAuthentication success in mvc 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing MVC 2 web application. I'm using FormsAuthentication for sign in users to my application. I want to generate an authentication token after users are successfully login to the application. I have to pass that authentication token to another application. Are there any best ways to accomplish this task using MVC2(.net framework 4.0). Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What "other application" - one you control or something else?

Comment: Thanks Brian for your reply. That application also control by us. Once user successfully login to main application I want to generate an authentication token and pass it to that application. Users who login to that application authenticated using that authentication token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At best, `FormsAuthentication` has a `GetAuthCookie` method which gets the cookie details for a logged-in user.  It's not really good for token-based authentication though.  You can, however, share the forms auth cookies across web applications.  There are restrictions involved, but [here is some documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx) ([and this for ASP.NET Core](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing.html)) to help understand where to begin.